# How do I create a Ubuntu script file that will open a .jar file?

Tags: command-line, bash, java

How do I create a Ubuntu terminal script that will open a .jar file?

This is what I have tried until now:

```
java -jar "/home/my-name/Desktop/Slow but Accurate/BulkNameChecker-slowbutaccurate.jar"
```

But it returns

> Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/my-name/Desktop/Slow but Accurate/BulkNameChecker-slowbutaccurate.jar

Comment: try this if Java installed :`java -jar Desktop/"Slow but Accurate"/BulkNameChecker-slowbutaccurate.jar`   or use cd command until you reach the Slow but Accurate folder and write `java -jar BulkNameChecker-slowbutaccurate.jar`

Answer (score 2):

1. your java started correctly (error message is from java)
2. java does not see that jar file.

I bet that if you do:

```
ls "/home/my-name/Desktop/Slow but Accurate/BulkNameChecker-slowbutaccurate.jar"
```

you will get:

```
ls: /home/my-name/Desktop/Slow but Accurate/BulkNameChecker-slowbutaccurate.jar: No such file or directory
```

so you can try:

```
ls "/home/"
ls "/home/my-name/"
ls "/home/my-name/Desktop/"
ls "/home/my-name/Desktop/Slow but Accurate/"
ls "/home/my-name/Desktop/Slow but Accurate/*.jar"
ls "/home/my-name/Desktop/Slow but Accurate/BulkNameChecker-slowbutaccurate.jar"
```

or:

```
find "/home/my-name" -name "*.jar"
```

to determine correct path.

Note1: you can use <kbd>tab</kbd> to assist you while typing a file names in terminal It is very handy.

Note2: If you use encrypted file system, or mounted when logged in and trying to run this script as another user, then the jar file might not be accessible, but most probable reason is a typo in the filename.